# Groin pain longer rides

Tags: pain

In the beginning of the season on my first ride over 100K about 2/3 into the ride started experiencing groin pain every time i would do a pedal stroke. it recovered after a few day and i am not able to ride about 1-2 hours depending on intensity without any pain, if i ride any longer the pain would flare up again i have tried different positions but that doesn’t seem to be the issue, i am taking a small break now to let it heal

Has anybody experienced anything similar where they can ride for 1-2 hours without any pain and anything longer than that and get a pinching pain in the groin with every pedal stroke?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm not sure we can really help you with any medical issues you may be having; you should probably consult a qualified sports medicine specialist.

Comment: I am not a doctor, nor do I play one on the internet, but it sure sounds like you strained/pulled a groin muscle and need to let it heal.

Comment: This could be anything from iliopsoas tendonitis to hip impingement (I’ve had both).

Comment: If this turns out a long term problem, look into recumbent cycling. It is a different concept but it suits many people.

Comment: I would follow the advice in this answer to a similar question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/88708/38270